# track a logged in users activity with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

**UPDATE:** I would not like to use the `cookie` method as the user can simply clear their cookies and then revisit the website, making the analytic / tracking attempt absolutely useless. Is there anyway possible to set a user ID at the login point (ideally from grabbing the user's actual user name, as mentioned below) and then just use the rest of google analytics custom events and page views and just associate it with the login name, every-time the user has logged in? **So, I could log into Google Analytics dashboard and see analytics & metric *per* logged in user?** *I would think a lot of people would be using GA for this.*

---

I am wanting to use google analytics to simply set a cookie of logged in user, or just a 'unique' user somehow.. and then associate the name of that user with my div element `<div class="user-name">..</div>` which displays my users dynamic user name, and then I simply would like to report custom events by that user, media play, downloads, clicks on buttons etc. Ideally similar to the older versions of GA where I can just code inline in the HTML links `<a href="#"...` I'm finding old information about setting up variables in the the dashboard, but it seems that information is still referencing the [old GA](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) as most of the info I'm finding. Any information with implementing this with new GA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a feature in Google Analytics called ["userID"](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en) that covers at least a part of your requirements. It allows you, for logged in users, to set an (anonymized) id from your backend system to recognize logged in visitors even after they have cleared their cookies or visit via another device. You need an extra view that will show only data for logged in visitors (and you need to accept some extra terms of use with Google Analytics and amend your privacy policy).

What this does not do, despite it's name, is to id individual users. For one the UserID is not exposed via the interface (you'd have to store it as a custom dimension yourself if you want that), secondly you must not use as a UserId anything that allows Google to determine the identity of a real person (e.g. we use a hash of the users e-mail address salted with a timestamp of the users registration date). So your idea of passing on the name of a user would violate Googles TOS and might result in termination of your account if they find out.

If you are interested, a while ago I wrote a [blog article on why tracking individual users is somewhat dubious und really unnecessary](http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/a-river-runs-through-it-or-the-elusive-user-scope-in-google-analytics/).